# Cast Hashmap<String,Serializable> to Hashmap<String,String> kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, casting

I am wondering is there any way to cast this or we have to manually iterate the map and put the values in a new map.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You can’t successfully cast one type into another unless the object is already a match for both types. String does not implement Serializable so you cannot successfully cast between them. You have to convert.

Comment: Unchecked cast: kotlin.collections.HashMap<String, Serializable?> /* = java.util.HashMap<String, Serializable?> */ to kotlin.collections.HashMap<String, String> /* = java.util.HashMap<String, String> */

Comment: Like I said, you cannot successfully cast it because String and Serializable are not the same. Read the documentation for the `Map.mapValues()` function. That is the easiest way to do this.